# Footer below list view fixed at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I was trying to have a footer below my listview.

This is how m doing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="#BE6D79"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/darkDetna"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listselector"
        android:paddingRight="0dip"
        android:text="Contact" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/faq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listselector"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="Terms And Conditions" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feedback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listselector"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="Feedback  " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fullSIte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listselector"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="Full Site" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here

but the problem is the list content is small or there is only one list item the footer ll be below the list view.

I want the footer to be fixed to the bottom of the screen.

Thanks in advance for you time and help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Better use `RelativeLayout`

Explain the implementation:

- add the footer view to be aligned at the bottom of the screen `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
- then add the listview above the footer layout `android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout1"`
- make your listview to fill the screen `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and 
  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Change at your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#BE6D79"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/darkDetna"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contactBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/listselector"
            android:paddingRight="0dip"
            android:text="Contact" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/faq"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/listselector"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:text="Terms And Conditions" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/feedback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/listselector"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:text="Feedback  " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fullSIte"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/listselector"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:text="Full Site" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten to set the list view above the view aligned at the bottom.

Comment: @madlymad, what if we have multiple footer views? How could we make the bottom most of them fixed?

Comment: @user5038993 whatever you need to scroll with the list can be added inside the list or as a footer of the list. Anything else can be part of an aligned bottom layout. If you need more complicated things like showing/hiding footers according to user scroll then you need to add custom code for scroll listeners or look for a library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and then add the view to the bottom of the RelativeLayout using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="#BE6D79"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/darkDetna"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listselector"
        android:paddingRight="0dip"
        android:text="Contact" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/faq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listselector"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="Terms And Conditions" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feedback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listselector"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="Feedback  " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fullSIte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listselector"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="Full Site" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use a RelativeLayout you can set `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` on the 2nd linearlayout

Comment: The other solutions were good but this one is the best for the current design. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelativeLayout` as root view of your Layout.